# Undo operation keeps resetting my settings

Tags: interface, shortcut, versions

im using blender v2.83.2, since this release I'am experiencing unwanted undo behaviour.

Every time I undo for example a brushstroke, at the same time, I am resetting the most recent changes in settings like, shapekeys oder simple brushsettings. Is there any toggle or other workaround for that which I have overseen?

best regards.

Comment: I think that it's a bug (I recently saw a reference of it in a youtube tutorial.. not 100% sure if it was Blender Guru or similar)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, known problem:
https://developer.blender.org/T71759

> Sculpt/Vertex/Weight Paint Brush Size Gets Undone After Undoing a
> Stroke
>
> **Short description of error**
>
> After changing the size, then doing a
> strike and immediately undoing it, the brush size gets undone as well.
>
> **Steps to reproduce**
>
> - Splash Screen > Sculpting or File > New > Sculpting.
> - Change the size of the brush ]
> - Sculpt: Only one stroke.
> - Undo

Comment: Thank you very much!